# Where can I download the Beta release for Ubuntu?

Tags: release-management

According to the 13.04 release schedule, the Beta 2 release for 13.04 was made available today (April 4). Does anyone know where I can download it? Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

For beta 2:

http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/

There are also ISOs for all of the other main distributions (among them Kubuntu and Xubuntu).

A few download links (more on the [13.04 wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/TechnicalOverview)):

Kubuntu: [cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/raring/beta-2](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/kubuntu/releases/raring/beta-2/)

Lubuntu: [cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/raring/beta-2](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/raring/beta-2/)

Xubuntu: [cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/raring/beta-2](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/xubuntu/releases/raring/beta-2/)

Answer (score 5):

Here is the Ubuntu 13.04 beta 2 : 32-bit
iso : [download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-beta2-desktop-i386.iso)
torrent : [download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-beta2-desktop-i386.iso.torrent)

Here is the Ubuntu 13.04 beta 2 : 64-bit
iso : [download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-beta2-desktop-amd64.iso)
torrent : [download](http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/ubuntu-13.04-beta2-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent)

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Ubuntu (Unity) beta 2 :

http://releases.ubuntu.com/13.04/